# Using sping's default beans in mvc-test framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I have the following controller definition:

```
public ResponseEntity switch(@PathVariable UUID userId, OAuth2Authentication authentication) { .. }
```

`authentication` object injected automatically, everything is fine. But once I want to test is with spring's mvc test framework I get:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: argument type mismatch
Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.oauth.controller.SwitchController.switch(java.util.UUID,org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication)]
Resolved arguments: 
[0] [type=java.util.UUID] [value=73e76822-a9d7-4ead-b876-7a4e6fced77f]
[1] [type=org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken] [value=org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken@a421525e: Principal: CLIENT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER]
```

and test is:

```
mvc.perform(post("/switch/" + USER.getUuid())
     .principal(new TestingAuthenticationToken(clientId, secret, authorities))
     .andExpect(status().isOk())
     .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: classic mistake of not programing to interfaces but concrete classes... Don't use `OAuth2Authentication` as that will tie your controller to only function in an OAuth2 environment. Instead use `Authentication` the common interface for those classes.